# Selecting multiple files with JFileChooser does not work

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So I am trying to have a user select multiple photos out of a directory. From the main GUI I open a window that lets the user select name and ID and then I use JFileChooser to get the photos. Everything works out so far - I just can't select more than one file at a time  which entirely defeats the purpose of this. Nothing is doable: Ctrl+Click or Shift+Arrowkeys. I already looked around that seems to be a popular problem.
My running version will include said GUI-Elements. Please explain to me how to make the selection of multiple files at once possible and if possible how this behaviour comes into existence.

```
JDialog ImportFenster= new JDialog(Fenster,
                        "Import von Nutzern");//Fenster is here the main GUI window use another one or set the first parameter here to "null"

                JTextField Name= new JTextField("Vorname [Leer] Name",30);
                JFormattedTextField ID =new JFormattedTextField(
                        NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
                ID.setColumns(4);
                JButton Enter = new JButton("OK");
                JButton Abort =new JButton("Abbruch");
                JLabel InfoID= new JLabel("Wird keine ID angegeben, wird eine automatisch erzeugt");
                //kinda stupid way to make your layout
                GridBagLayout ImportLayout= new GridBagLayout();
                GridBagConstraints LayoutConstraints=new GridBagConstraints();

                ImportFenster.setLayout(ImportLayout);

                LayoutConstraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
                LayoutConstraints.gridwidth=3;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=0;
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=5;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=5;
                ImportFenster.add(InfoID,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.gridwidth=1;
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=1;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
                ImportFenster.add(ID,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=1;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
                ImportFenster.add(Name,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=3;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=3;
                ImportFenster.add(Enter,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.ipadx=10;
                LayoutConstraints.ipady=25;
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=3;
                ImportFenster.add(Abort,LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=1;
                ImportFenster.add(new JLabel("Nutzer-ID:"),LayoutConstraints);
                LayoutConstraints.gridx=0;
                LayoutConstraints.gridy=2;
                ImportFenster.add(new JLabel("Nutzer-Name:"),LayoutConstraints);

                ImportFenster.setSize(750,350);
                ImportFenster.setVisible(true);
                Enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  //before this the codes does some shit                                                        DateiAuswahl.showOpenDialog(Fenster);
                        DateiAuswahl.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                        DateiAuswahl.setVisible(true);
                        DateiAuswahl.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
                        DateiAuswahl.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
                        File[] NewFaces = {};
                        if(DateiAuswahl.showOpenDialog(Fenster)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                           NewFaces=DateiAuswahl.getSelectedFiles();
//after this stuff happens
                        }
}
```

EDIT: I am a dummy. Really. Put the setMultiSelectionEnabled() part before opening the dialoguie and presto! It works. Now I have to clean up some other issues...

Comment: `DateiAuswahl.setVisible(true);` is not required

Comment: I removed `DateiAuswahl.setVisible(true);` and tested it and it works fine

Comment: Yeah it does "work" but with this modification the problem persists

Comment: I did a test (on MacOS) and it works fine, which suggests that the problem is somewhere which isn't immediately obvious based on your out-of-context snippet, consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: I also see that you might be calling `showOpenDialog`, best to clean that up and remove any ambiguity